# static method does not run it in main class

Tags: java, class, netbeans, program-entry-point

Console prints illegal start of expression. Method is for finding letters in input String. Is it different when the method is under main or above it? Could netBeans cause the issue?

```
  package wars;

 public class Wars {

static String printerError(String s) {
    int a = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (!s.substring(i, i + 1).equals("a")
                || !s.substring(i, i + 1).equals("b")
                || !s.substring(i, i + 1).equals("c")
                || !s.substring(i, i + 1).equals("d")
                || !s.substring(i, i + 1).equals("e")
                || !s.substring(i, i + 1).equals("f")
                || !s.substring(i, i + 1).equals("g")
                || !s.substring(i, i + 1).equals("h")
                || !s.substring(i, i + 1).equals("i")
                || !s.substring(i, i + 1).equals("j")
                || !s.substring(i, i + 1).equals("k")
                || !s.substring(i, i + 1).equals("l")
                || !s.substring(i, i + 1).equals("m")) {
            a++;
        }
    }
    return a + "/" + s.length();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(Wars.printerError("pokemon"));
}
```

}

Comment: This code passes compilation for me. Of course, it produces no output.

Comment: error stack please?

Comment: The output is through console i forgot tu put it there but still it will not compile.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - illegal start of expression
 at wars.Wars.main(Wars.java:7)

Comment: What is at line 7 of your script? Did you post all of it here?

Comment: At the 7th line printerError("pokemon");

Comment: Then please update your question with the actual code, as that will give us more insight as an error corresponding to a different code

Comment: Yes, but it the same even without printerError("pokemon"); I mean when the line is empty.

Comment: Is your file called wars.java or Wars.java?

Comment: It is called Wars.java

Comment: Well, the code you posted seems to work fine: https://ideone.com/Ft4NYH So I guess the problem is something outside of the code.

Comment: What can i do to find out what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference. If you want to know the result, you might want to modify the code as shown below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println(printerError("pokemon"));
}
```

Comment: I did it but output is same:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - illegal start of expression at wars.Wars.main(Wars.java:7)

Comment: @Tbijo54 How about  System.out.println(Wars.printerError("pokemon")); ?

Comment: Still the same.

Comment: @Tbijo54 How about the package name? 'package wars;' Did you call it good?

Comment: It was automatically called package wars.

Comment: @Tbijo54 If you can not do any of the above actions, I'd like to save it and run it again. Because there is no problem in the code.

Comment: @Tbijo There is nothing wrong with the code. I used Eclipse and found no errors, and it is clean code. It seems to be a problem with Netbeans.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be working for me without any errors.

You aren't printing the returned value. Add the following line to the main method.

```
System.out.println(printerError("pokemon"));
```

Comment: I added System.out.println(printerError("pokemon"));
Still does not work I am using netBeans can that be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

It works, you just don't print any result

Comment: I added System.out.println(printerError("pokemon"));
Still does not work I am using netBeans can that be an issue.